# Need to extract a paragraph alone from a file and make it a single line

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a text file as a input where I have n number of paragraphs with line break for each paragraph.
I need to replace every single paragraph as a single line

Let me consider a small example

my input is:

```
Stackoverflow is the best site for
java novice beginners 
it helps them to identify the solutions for unsolved problems
```

my output should be:

```
Stackoverflow is the best site for java novice beginners  it helps them to identify the solutions for unsolved problems Please help me to fix it.
```

I tried with split, regex. Nothing could save me. :(

I need to replace a new line with space if it has any contents

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: I think it would be better to parse such input: `Stackoverflow is the site for java developers on which they discuss really interesting and complex questions. It is not for asking "how I can write my programm" for beginners.`

Comment: Show your code so far and explain how it didn't work.

Comment: str=str.replaceAll("    ", "");
   str=str.replaceAll("  ", "");

str=str.replace("\n"," ");

Answer (score 0):

First of all sorry for my english.
I think you could read each line and then concat each line in a String. Something like this:

```
File yourFile= null;
        FileReader fr = null;
        BufferedReader br = null;
      //Here you will store the merged paragraphs
        String mergedParagraphs = new String();
        try
        {

            yourFile= new File ("path to your file");
            fr = new FileReader (yourfile);
            br = new BufferedReader(fr);

            String line;

            while((line=br.readLine())!=null)
            {
                mergedParagraphs = mergedParagraphs + line;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            // Here the input file is closed
            try
            {
                if( null != fr )
                {
                    fr.close();
                }
            }catch (Exception e2)
            {
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

I hope it helps you